# iphone 4 higher resolution pics vs 3gs

Tags: iphone

i just have a 3gs for testing (here in romania i still cant get a iphone 4)

When I just create full screen images for iPhone 4 .. would they be displayed resized on the 3gs?

I just cant make a bundle version for 3gs and 4 with 2 times my images, they are already a lot. Do I have to make now 2 Apps ??

Could this be a trick: In my xib i define a 320x480 UIImageView (it will be resized automaticly on the iPhone4) when I there define "scale to fill" and make high resolution images, would they come more sharp on the iPhone 4?

Now I am just wondering how to work best right now for big animations.
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out in my case its fine to use higher resolution pics into a 320x480 frame like for 3GS and make Aspect FILL.

When I test on a iPhone 4 Simulator it shows much higher resolution and same on iPad if I click 2x :)

Answer (score 0):

you can also create alternative high resolution images with a name ending in "@2x". so if you have an image called "arrow.png", create one with twice the resolution called "arrow@2x.png" and the iphone 4 will use that.

check out this article: http://thomasmaier.me/2010/06/dealing-with-iphone-4-resolution-2x-inside-of-photoshop/

Comment: as mentioned..i already have a lot of images :) 15MB just to make it 2x again minimum 22MB additional. I just like to keep it small

Answer (score 0):

Try it and find out, but my suspicion is that even if they do work, they won't work on OS 3.0 or OS 3.1, and plenty of people have not upgraded yet.

Also note that even if it *displays* them at half-size, I'm pretty sure that they'll still be "@2x" images. This means they'll use more memory and generally perform worse.

What's wrong with adding a handful of new images? The normal-size images are a lot smaller than the @2x images.

**EDIT:** If you have a lot of images, you may find it beneficial to use JPEGs where appropriate (e.g. for photos or photo-like backgrounds). I'm not sure, but I think they should work with +[UIImage imageNamed:] though you might have to specify ".jpg" explicitly.

Comment: And remember to save them as flattened images, if you're making them in Fireworks or something like that. Much smaller file sizes.

Comment: thx.. but already its over 15MB ! by 20kb each pic...:) ... no prob.. i will find a solution.

Comment: Yeah after making graphics for iPhone, iPhone 4, and iPad, my app (which *should* have just a few graphics) is like 8 MB haha.

Comment: A quick way to remove extraneous PNG chunks is to run it through `pngcrush -rem all`, which only preserves the required IHDR and IDAT chunks.